# Json Entity List with Play Framework

Tags: extjs, playframework

I try to run this code but I get a NULL exception.

Java Code :

```
public static void updateData(List<Users> users){
   for(Users u : users){ //Erros
      System.out.println(u.name); // Error
   }
}
```

Extjs Code :

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',

    api: {
        update: '/Application/updateData'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'users',
        successProperty: 'success'
    }
}
```

Json Array :

```
[{"name":"Ed","email":"aa@aa.com"},{"name":"Ez","email":"bb@bb.com"}]
```

Please tell me how to bind a JSON array to an Entity List on Play Framework 1.2.2.

Comment: Did you try this kind of binder? http://www.playframework.org/community/snippets/6

Answer (score 1):

If you change the parameter of your method to **body** you are able to read the entire JSON string:

```
public static void updateData(String body){
```

I then use GSON (Play! uses the same lib) to deserialize the JSON response, example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = gson.fromJson(body, User.class);
```

For me it works fine, but this might not be the best way, I'm not sure.

Cheers.

EDIT:
I just saw that your ExtJS is returning 1 object wrapped in a array, if you always return ONE object no need for array so add to your ExtJS code (if you use ExtJS 4):

```
allowSingle: false
```